# I want to update two tables in single query in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public bool UpdateLevelDetailsList(List<LevelDetailsDALDTO> LevelDetailsObjToUpdate)
    {
        bool result = false;
        //List<LevelDetail> editLevelDetails = DBContext.LevelDetails.Where(g => g.LevelID == a.LevelID).ToList();
        List<LevelDetail> levelDetails = DBContext.LevelDetails.ToList();
        List<VisioShapeData> VisioData = DBContext.VisioShapeDatas.ToList();

        foreach (LevelDetailsDALDTO a in LevelDetailsObjToUpdate)
        {
            //List<LevelDetail> editLevelDetails = DBContext.LevelDetails.Where(g => g.LevelID == a.LevelID).ToList();
            List<LevelDetail> editLevelDetails = levelDetails.Where(x => x.LevelID == a.LevelID).ToList();
            List<VisioShapeData> updatevisiodata = VisioData.Where(x => x.ID == a.ID).ToList();
            if (a.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                a.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (a.ModifiedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                a.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

            if (editLevelDetails != null)
            {
                foreach (LevelDetail b in editLevelDetails)
                {
                    b.Cost += a.Cost;
                    b.Time += a.Time;
                    b.Responsible = b.Responsible + "," + a.Responsible;
                    b.ModifiedBy = a.ModifiedBy;
                    b.ModifiedDate = a.ModifiedDate;

                }
                if (updatevisiodata != null)
                {
                    foreach (VisioShapeData c in updatevisiodata)
                    {
                        c.Level4Id = a.LevelID;
                    }
                }
                if (DBContext.SaveChanges() > 0)
                    result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

want to combine these two statement in

```
List<LevelDetail> editLevelDetails = levelDetails.Where(x => x.LevelID == a.LevelID).ToList();
List<VisioShapeData> updatevisiodata = VisioData.Where(x => x.ID == a.ID).ToList();
```

and

Comment: And what you tried?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and somehow this question body does not look like you have finished it writing?